# Can I use multani mud bar for tayammum?

Tags: wudu

Once I used multani mud bar for tayammum, but i'm not 100% sure about it. Can I use Multani mud bar for tayammum? Since its also of mud..and easy to carry anywhere..If anybody knows please make me sure of it..

Its not soap, its just mud bar.. im not 100% sure about other ingredients, but it seems like whole mud. i've attached a picture similar to it..[enter link description here](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-udYXryn6x9M/UTYhO6GEZcI/AAAAAAAACbw/8rcTLM3KVfY/s1600/MultaniMitti.jpg&imgrefurl=http://shahtajmaqsood.blogspot.com/2012/04/tip-of-week.html&h=835&w=1024&tbnid=EToO6qd5kZMoOM:&zoom=1&docid=Pmvc-iFLmDFa6M&ei=gK3YVMPoFoLn8AWC6IDQAg&tbm=isch&ved=0CEsQMyggMCA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the it for doing tayyamum as its one form of soil an pure/clean too. (its my own opinion and i am not a scholar) so you should better consult a scholar.if you are in pakistan, i can give you contact of few